# How to connect android studio testing GUI to gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, mockito, android-testing, robolectric

There are some tests in my android project and configured CI
Before deploying tests are launched using gradle wrapper(4.10.3)
95% of tests are robolectric tests

And there are cases when these tests are not passing because of different reasons, but the problem is that when i run them from android studio GUI tests are working fine(passing).

For example i use mockito for mocking and mock-maker-inline, i have this MockMaker in core module that is used in all other modules, if i launch tests from android studio - they are passing, if i launch using gradle wrapper - they are all failing. It can be solved by adding MockMaker in module, where i have tests, but still why it is working from android studio, but not working from console?

My test running options:
[image: Default test running options]

Case when i remove mock maker from locations module(dependent on core module with enabled mock-maker) 
All tests are filing with this error

[image: removed mock maker]

But when i run with android studio tests are passing and everything is fine.

What is the difference between these two launches?(default launch type from android studio and gradlew testDebug).
And is there a way to connect my custom gradle test task with android studio tests gui?

Comment: Can you give more details about the CI you're running on and any logs generated by the failing tests on your CI? This will help readers to better understand your problem and help you.

Comment: I mentioned CI, but it is not related to this issue, if i launch these tests using gradle wrapper(from console, away from CI pipeline) - they will still fail, but in android studio they will pass.

Comment: Without seeing the logs/output, it's pretty difficult to debug this.

Comment: Actually tests are failing with different reasons, the all i want to know is why they are failing with gradle wrapper and not failing using android studio, what is the difference between these two types of launches

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference between the GUI and running from terminal is that the Gradle wrapper will execute the tests of different modules concurrently if you have it enabled in gradle.properties:

`org.gradle.parallel=true`

If you have tests in different modules acting upon the same singleton, or the same mocks, then you can run into any number of conflicts.

Comment: I have org.gradle.parallel enabled.
Tested with only one test case, still not working.
Updated question with some additional information